# Getting QGIS Server GetCapabilities working on Windows?

Tags: windows, server, qgis-server

I followed this tutorial: http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/ but nothing happens.

[image]

And when I try to open it this error message appears
[image]

So I tried to follow httpd_qgis.conf edition step from http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial but it gives me the same error.

[image]

I think I didn't need that step because I can see "mod_fcgid" in my apache modules directory

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Had the same problem and solved adding C:\OSGeo4W\bin to the system path

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by manually installing the fcgi package in OSGeo4W.

according to this ticket:

http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/395

the package should now be selected as dependency by default.

Answer (score 0):

I compared my version (that works on Windows 7)

> localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&SRS=EPSG:4326&REQUEST=GetMap&map=C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/QGIS_WEBPROJECT.qgs&BBOX=49.5311,-123.4173,49.5211,-122.1973&WIDTH=1000&HEIGHT=1000&Styles=default&LAYERS=LAYERNAME_WGS84&FORMAT=image/png

I have a project saved in the directory

C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/QGIS_WEBPROJECT.qgs

(is in WGS84) a bounding box (Vancouver)

Image height/width (pixels format)

Result
[image]